# What vector.size() of a struct will return?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a struct called `Tcouleur` which contains 3 `unsigned char` elements, and a vector of `Tcouleur` called `compteur`. When I use `compteur.size()`, the number returned is the number of `Tcouleur` or the number of `unsigned char` ?

I'm pretty new to vectors.

I have populated the vector in a for loop which number (of loop) depends on a variable.

Comment: Have you thought about running your code and seeing what happens?

Comment: Yes it does return the number of items in the vector as per the documentation

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks, I will be more carefull next time !

Comment: @LogicStuff I did, but the value was so high, I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compteur` has nothing to do with the `unsigned char`s in your struct. It just keeps track of how many elements are stored within. And an "element" in your case is a `Tcouleur` object.